# toggle bool in an object

Tags: java, oop, boolean, toggle

So my code works fine and everything, however the only thing really bugging me is that my IDE is throwing up a recommendation saying "the value true assigned to 'alarmState' is never used", I can't get rid of alarm state from my code as it throws up more errors. Does anyone know why this is happening, and if so redo my code so its as efficient without the menacing grey underline under my variable.

```
            case 3 :
                System.out.print("The alarm state is now : ");
                boolean alarmState = clockObject.isAlarmSet();
                clockObject.setAlarmSet(alarmState ^= true); //This value
                System.out.print(clockObject.isAlarmSet());
                break;
```

Comment: apparently it didn't make alarmState bold but just put it in **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x ^= y` is shorthand for `x = x ^ y`. Since you don't need the result of the assignment, you can just say

```
clockObject.setAlarmSet(alarmState ^ true); // use ^ instead of ^=
```

which can be further simplified to

```
clockObject.setAlarmSet(!alarmState);
```

Comment: I agree that is an issue. But it shouldn't be the cause of his issue "alarmState is never used" ?

Comment: I don't think so. That is a very specific message when a variable isn't used. It is not used to identify questionable code.

Comment: Oops, I deleted the comment @EduardoDennis is referring to. (I'd written that technically the result of the assignment *is* used, because it's passed to the `setAlarmSet` method, but the IDE was nonetheless identifying questionable code.)